# using JQuery to convert html tr tags to uppercase for string comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS function:

```
function tblFilter(colToFilter) {
var tableToFilter = $("#notesGrid").find("tr");
var columnToFilter = colToFilter;

$.each(columnToFilter, function (i) {
    tableToFilter = tableToFilter.filter(":contains'" + columnToFilter + "')");
});

tableToFilter.show();

};
```

colToFilter is uppercase and I want to convert what I am comparing to to uppercase as well to ensure case insensitivity.

I have tried this:

```
function tblFilter(colToFilter) {
    var tableToFilter = $("#notesGrid").find("tr");
    var columnToFilter = colToFilter;

    $.each(columnToFilter, function (i) {
        tableToFilter = tableToFilter[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().filter(":contains'" + columnToFilter + "')");
    });

    tableToFilter.show();

};
```

However it fails saying:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

Comment: `.filter()` is the error. when you call `tableToFilter[i]`, `tableToFilter[i]` is not a jQuery object anymore. So `.filter()` is not it's property or method.

Comment: Reigel you are correct.  both of the suggestions return :

>Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method


Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you include what `columnToFilter` is?  like what are we expecting here. is it html, string, etc...

Comment: hmm... can you clear out what you are trying to achieve? like "wanna remove this `tr`... and... I will use filter" , something like that.

Comment: I am taking an input form a text box and I want to loop through a table and search the <td> </td> to find the value of the string passed in.

Then I want to return to the screen a table containing only the rows that contain the string.

Barry

Comment: Anyone got any other ideas on this??

Answer (score 1):

Try to use match() method of strings.

Comment: I believe you can use a regex with match so using a case insensitive regex would do the trick here

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a try with the following?

```
$(tableToFilter[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase()).filter()
```

Comment: Thanks airbai.  I tried that but it still didn't work.

Reigel - columnToFilter is derived from $("#note").val().toUpperCase() - essentially it is an uppercase string